# Best way to programmatically get linked objects per stereotype

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to programmatically (javascript) get a linked object of a given element per stereotype, even if it is more than one level up.

So, for example in the next figure, I expect to get Obj1 from both el1 and el2, but never Obj2.
[image]

I have this solution already but is seems not too elegant and its time consuming:

```
function count(main_str, sub_str) 
    {
    main_str += '';
    sub_str += '';
    if (sub_str.length <= 0) 
    {
        return main_str.length + 1;
    }
       subStr = sub_str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
       return (main_str.match(new RegExp(subStr, 'gi')) || []).length;
    }

function getLinkedObjects(objectID, connectionType, end_or_start) {
    //This function gets the objects linked to the given objectID. It can be filtered by 'connectionType' and by weather the given object is in start or end position.
    if (connectionType == '' || connectionType == 'any') {
        var connector = ""
    } else {
        var connector = " and Connector_type = '"+connectionType+"'"
        }
    if (end_or_start == 'start') {
        var SQLquery = "select obj.Object_ID, obj.Name from (t_object obj inner join (select * from t_connector where start_object_ID = "+objectID+connector+") q on q.End_object_ID = obj.Object_ID) where obj.Object_ID <> "+objectID+connector
    } else if (end_or_start == 'start') {
        var SQLquery = "select obj.Object_ID, obj.Name from (t_object obj inner join (select * from t_connector where end_object_ID = "+objectID+connector+") q on q.start_object_ID = obj.Object_ID) where obj.Object_ID <> "+objectID+connector
    } else if (end_or_start == '' || end_or_start == 'both') {
        var SQLquery = "select distinct obj.Object_ID, obj.Name from (t_object obj inner join (select * from t_connector where (start_object_ID = "+objectID+connector+" or end_object_ID = "+objectID+connector+")) q on (q.Start_object_ID = obj.Object_ID or q.End_object_ID = obj.Object_ID)) where obj.Object_ID <> "+objectID+connector
    } else {
        var SQLquery = ""
    }
    var conn_elements = Repository.GetElementSet(SQLquery, 2);
    return conn_elements;
    }
    
    
function getObjectStream(elemid, stereotype) {
    //This function gets all the stream of objects and/or blocks linked to the given objectID.
    var i = 0
    var streams = []
    var linked_objs = getLinkedObjects(elemid, "", "both");
    for (var l = 0; l < linked_objs.Count; l++) {
        var level1 = getLinkedObjects(linked_objs.GetAt(l).ElementID, "", "both");
        if (linked_objs.GetAt(l).Stereotype == stereotype) {
            var stream = "l0--  " + linked_objs.GetAt(l).Name
            streams.push(stream)    
            break
        } else {
            for (var l1 = 0; l1 < level1.Count; l1++) {
                var level2 = getLinkedObjects(level1.GetAt(l1).ElementID, "", "both");
                if (level1.GetAt(l1).Stereotype == stereotype) {
                    var stream = "l0--  " + linked_objs.GetAt(l).Name + " l1--  " + level1.GetAt(l1).Name
                    streams.push(stream)
                    break
                } else {
                    for (var l2 = 0; l2 < level2.Count; l2++) {
                        if (level2.GetAt(l2).Stereotype == stereotype) {
                            var stream = "l0--  " + linked_objs.GetAt(l).Name + " l1--  " + level1.GetAt(l1).Name + " l2--  " + level2.GetAt(l2).Name
                            streams.push(stream)
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var w = ''
    var level = 5
    for (var f = 0; f < streams.length; f++) {
        levels = count(streams[f], "--")
        if (levels < level) {
            level = levels - 1
            w = streams[f]
            }   
        }       
        var le = "l"+level+"-- "
        var n = w.search(le) + 5;
        var winner = w.substring(n, w.lenght);
        return winner
    }
    
function main() {
    var linked_per_stereotype = getObjectStream(1234, "A");
    Session.Output(linked_per_stereotype);
}

main();
```

Any suggestions for a better approach for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Put in what you tried and where you got stuck. It might be re-opened then. You won't get teh codez on request here.

Comment: P.S. Tagging with Javascript got all the JS kids looking at it and not knowing that you're using EA.

Comment: alright, thanks @qwerty_so

Comment: I've edited the question. Is it possible to reopen it now?

Comment: Do you need all linked elements with a certain stereotype, or just the first one you encounter? In that case do you need the closest one (breadth first) or the first one if you follow the first link (depth first). Is there a maximum of levels you need to search?

Comment: @GeertBellekens I need the closest one. If I could set the max levels value depending on the situation, that would be preferable, if not, 4 levels should be enough. 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't really have time right now to write an answer. You could probably write a single query that returns all 4 levels at once, but since you only need the closes one, it might be faster to query level by level. Make sure you call your operation recursively to get to the next level, and make sure you don't circle back.

Comment: @GeertBellekens querying in each level is already what my solution is doing. Maybe thats the best approach then...

Comment: Yes, except that you don't call your method recursively, which makes it less elegant with a lot of repeated code. Also your code risks ending up in circles some point. (think A -> B -> C -> D -> B , which will keep circling B -> C -> D -> B ->...)

Comment: If i'm looking for B, it stops the loop when it finds it. Why do you say it will circle?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with JS and it depends on your model. So just thinking loud: if there were a limited number of the desired stereotypes (and having language construct like in Python which might or might not be present in JS) I would just query all elements having the stereotype along with their connectors in a `JOIN` and make a hash of the result by object ID. So I could traverse simply by indexing the hash from the connector source/end ID. I would assume the number of stereotyped elements is rather low so that would be an approach.

If your model were huge and having tons of these stereotypes there might be no way around single queries. Maybe Geert has something doing that in one go.

Comment: I only need to get linked objects with a given (only one) stereotype. If its not existing in one level, i need to check the next and so forth. My solution (script) already does this, but I was hoping there was a better and more elegant way of doing this.